# Stranges lines in my table

Tags: tables, floats

I have a basic example of my template that return me an error. I create a new float that's call "quadro". But when I use "\begin{quadro}" appears some strange lines

```
\documentclass[
article, % indica que é um artigo acadêmico
12pt, % tamanho da fonte
oneside, % para impressão apenas no verso. Oposto a twoside
a4paper,, % tamanho do papel. 
english, % idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}          % Pacote abntex2 - mais detalhes - https://code.google.com/p/abntex2/wiki/TOC?tm=6

% Pacotes fundamentais 
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{}
% Paginas com as citações 
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
% Citações padrão ABNT

\usepackage{times}  % Usar a fonte Times
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{nomencl} % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage{color}  % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{subfig}             % Subfiguras com títulos
\usepackage{caption}            % Nota de rodapé - figuras
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{framed}
\ifpdf%
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\else
\usepackage{lscape}  % Modo paísagem
\fi           
\usepackage{epstopdf}           % Para figuras de alta resolução EPS
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype} 
% para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{ctable}             % Suporte para configuração de tabelas - rodapés fixos
\usepackage{longtable}          % Para tabelas em landscape
\usepackage{booktabs}           % Ajustes tabelas
\usepackage{cleveref}           % Referenciar tabelas com ctable package \cref{}
\usepackage{float}              % H - Fixar posição de figura/tabela - evitar flutuação se necessário
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}    % Colorir tabelas
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http
\usepackage{longtable, ltcaption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
%\usepackage[pdfspacing,floatperchapter]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{scrhack} % load after "float"
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  rightmargin,
  contents={%
    \parbox[b][\layerheight][c]{\dimexpr\footskip+\footheight\relax}{%
      \hfill\rotatebox{90}{\pagemark}}}
]{lscape.foot}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight\relax,
  width=\dimexpr\headsep+\headheight\relax,
  contents={\hfill\rotatebox{90}{\headmark}\hspace*{\headsep}}
]{lscape.head}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{lscape}{lscape.foot,lscape.head}
\usepackage{trivfloat}
\trivfloat{chart} % cria nova lista com nome: ``char''
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% CONFIGURAÇÃO DO PAPER
%--------------------------------------------------------------

% Definição de margens - package geometry
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

% Recuo do parágrafo :
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro %  \onelineskip
\setlength{\parskip}{0.0cm}  


% Espaçamento entre linhas
%\SingleSpacing
\doublespacing
%\OnehalfSpacing

% Informações de autoria PDF e cores de links e citações
% Definir cor de citação
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{30,50,100}
\hypersetup{
pagebackref=true,
pdftitle={\@title}, 
pdfauthor={\@author},
pdfsubject={Artigo},
pdfcreator={LaTeX},
pdfkeywords={.}{.}, 
colorlinks=true, % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=blue,     % color of internal links
citecolor=blue,     % color of links to bibliography
filecolor=magenta,  % color of file links
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksdepth=4
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolário}

%\newenvironment{proof}[1][Prova]
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

% Ajustamento de colunas de tabelas
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---

% CAPA E/OU FOLHA DE ROSTO
% -------------------------------------------------------------
\titulo{Transferências governamentais: uma análise de seu impacto no comportamento orçamentário dos municípios brasileiros}
\instituicao{
    Universidade Federal da Paraíba 
    \par
    Centro de Ciências Sociais Aplicadas
    \par
    Programa de Pós-Graduação em Economia}
\autor{PEDRO JORGE HOLANDA ALVES}
\local{João Pessoa - PB}
\data{2019}
\orientador{Dr. Jevuks Matheus Araújo}
\tipotrabalho{Dissertação}

\preambulo{Dissertação apresentada ao Programa de Pós-Graduação em Economia da Universidade Federal da Paraíba - UFPB como parte dos requisitos necessários à obtenção do título de mestre em Economia.}
% ----------------------------------------------------------


%-----------------------------------------
% Abaixo são chamadas as partes/capítulos
% considerando alguns configurações
%----------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\newpage

% -------------------------------
% Inserir lista de tabelas
% -------------------------------

% \pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
% \listoftables*
% \cleardoublepage


% -------------------------------
% Inserir lista de tabelas, quadros, gráficos e figuras
% -------------------------------

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{quadro}{tbhp}{crt}
\floatname{quadro}{Quadro}
\restylefloat*{quadro}

\newfloat{grafico}{tbp}{ext}
\floatname{grafico}{Gráfico}
\restylefloat*{grafico}

\begingroup
  \let\clearpage\relax
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax

    \listoftables
    \newpage

    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Quadro}
    \listof{quadro}{Lista de Quadros}
    \newpage

\endgroup       

% -------------------------------
% Inserir lista de ilustrações
% -------------------------------

%\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
%\listoffigures*
%\cleardoublepage

% -------------------------------
% Inserir o sumario
% -------------------------------

\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newpage

\textual

%TABLE 1
%\parbox{7cm}{\
\begin{table}[H]\footnotesize
  \centering
    \parbox{15.5cm}{\caption{Distribuição das receitas médias municipais e estaduais de acordo com as Grandes Regiões do Brasil, 1985-2015, por porcentagem}\label{tab01}}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}
    \begin{tabular}{rccccc|ccccc}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Receita Tributária}      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Transferências Correntes} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{MUNICÍPIOS} & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 \\
    \midrule
    Brasil & 11.37 & 22.66 & 18.08 & 18.07 & 19.48 & 60.26 & 60.92 & 65.67 & 66.86 & 64.13 \\
    Centro-Oeste & 9.53  & 24.84 & 12.11 & 12.98 & 15.71 & 66.83 & 75.12 & 74.28 & 72.31 & 71.90 \\
    Nordeste & 6.90  & 12.12 & 9.54  & 9.68  & 18.05 & 60.56 & 79.25 & 79.27 & 80.74 & 84.70 \\
    Norte & 5.80  & 13.27 & 9.35  & 10.33 & 31.69 & 56.73 & 76.73 & 77.45 & 79.05 & 86.47 \\
    Sudeste & 22.04 & 26.43 & 23.81 & 23.84 & 19.75 & 50.59 & 52.64 & 58.44 & 59.42 & 49.62 \\
    Sul & 12.57 & 19.86 & 15.19 & 15.41 & 17.40 & 66.57 & 67.31 & 65.41 & 65.88 & 71.21 \\
    \midrule
    ESTADOS & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 \\
    \midrule
    Brasil & 79.14 & 65.59 & 63.35 & 62.34 & 61.91 & 18.66 & 24.22 & 22.31 & 24.53 & 22.43 \\
    Centro-Oeste & 59.79 & 50.11 & 58.70 & 62.58 & 58.44 & 31.08 & 40.97 & 27.74 & 22.75 & 20.98 \\
    Nordeste & 56.38 & 50.25 & 47.28 & 45.79 & 48.49 & 34.64 & 43.69 & 39.48 & 43.19 & 40.26 \\
    Norte & 45.18 & 42.68 & 41.85 & 41.15 & 41.61 & 62.08 & 49.87 & 48.53 & 48.87 & 44.35 \\
    Sudeste & 82.70 & 77.23 & 72.10 & 71.02 & 70.09 & 9.07  & 13.13 & 11.95 & 13.99 & 11.94 \\
    Sul & 84.69 & 62.59 & 67.33 & 67.21 & 68.29 & 10.50 & 18.34 & 19.61 & 22.35 & 19.90 \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Fonte: Elaboração própria com base em dados da Secretaria do Tesouro Nacional.}}
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{flushleft}
    \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{table}%

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'fpm'
\begin{quadro}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Coeficientes do FPM interior por faixa de habitantes.}
  \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{p{10.785em}lrr}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .839,  .89,  .737} \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{Faixa de habitantes} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{10.085em}|}{Faixa de habitantes} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{Até 10.188} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.6} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 61.129 a 71.316} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.4} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 10.189 a 13.584} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.8} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 71.317 a 81.504} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.6} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 13.585 a 16.980} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.0} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 81.505 a 91.692} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.8} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 16.981 a 23.772} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 91.693 a 101.880} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.0} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 23.773 a 30.564} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.4} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 101.881 a 115.464} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.2} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 30.565 a 37.356} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.6} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 115.465 a 129.048} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.4} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 37.357 a 44.148} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.8} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 129.049 a 142.632} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.6} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 44.149 a 50.940} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.0} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 142.633 a 156.216} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.8} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 50.941 a 61.128} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{Acima de 156.216} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4.0} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{p{30.42em}}{Fonte: Decreto Lei nº 1.881/1981.} \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab02}%
\end{quadro}%

\end{document}
```

This is an example of output

[image]

Someone knows how can I remove theese lines?

Comment: What are the strange lines?

Comment: Are you aware, your code results in an error message warning you about the incompatibility of `subcaption` and `subfig`? Decide for one of these packages.

Comment: Are the "strange lines"  you refer to the horizontal lines above "Quadro 1..."  and below "Fonte:..."? If so, the are caused by `\floatstyle{ruled}`.

Comment: Why all those `\multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}` in the first column? They're completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Bernard: The table seems to have been auto-created (See`% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'fpm'`). In my experience, Excel2LaTeX typically does a better job though...

Comment: @leandriis: A spreadsheet which isn't even able to round the width of a column 0.001 em accuracy!), that would make a nice  advert for MS :)

Comment: Are you referring to the vertical lines?  That's caused by the `|` in your `\multicolumn{1}` commands.  `booktabs` explicitly does not work well with vertical lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may liked the following solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[article,  % indica que é um artigo acadêmico
                12pt,    % tamanho da fonte
                oneside, % para impressão apenas no verso. Oposto a twoside
                a4paper, % tamanho do papel.
                english, % idioma adicional para hifenização
                brazil,  % o último idioma é o principal do documento
                oldfontcommands % for compability with "copyrightbox"
                ]{abntex2}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Coeficientes do FPM interior por faixa de habitantes.}
    \label{tab:???}% label name for referencin
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.05}
\copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tabular}{lclc}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .839,  .89,  .737} 
Faixa de habitantes & Coeficiente   
                            & Faixa de habitantes   & Coeficiente   \\
    \hline
Até 10.188          & 0.6   & De 61.129 a 71.316    & 2.4   \\
De 10.189 a 13.584  & 0.8   & De 71.317 a 81.504    & 2.6   \\
De 13.585 a 16.980  & 1.0   & De 81.505 a 91.692    & 2.8   \\
    \addlinespace
De 16.981 a 23.772  & 1.2   & De 91.693 a 101.880   & 3.0   \\
De 23.773 a 30.564  & 1.4   & De 101.881 a 115.464  & 3.2   \\
De 30.565 a 37.356  & 1.6   & De 115.465 a 129.048  & 3.4   \\
    \addlinespace
De 37.357 a 44.148  & 1.8   & De 129.049 a 142.632  & 3.6   \\
De 44.149 a 50.940  & 2.0   & De 142.633 a 156.216  & 3.8   \\
De 50.941 a 61.128  & 2.2   & Acima de 156.216      & 4.0   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    {Fonte: Decreto Lei nº 1.881/1981.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Note:*

- Do you really need al those packages loaded in preamble of your document?
- In your preamble you load some packages twice or even more
- Some loaded packages are not compatible (subfigure, subcaprion)
  some packages overwrite other (`lscape`, `pdflscape`)
- We are interested only for MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document, which can be compiled as it is, and which in preamble load only packages relevant to your problem). In your document example is easy to lost ...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Removed all the prefix suffix in the original code

Inserted alternating colors with `\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}` the colors can be varied as per choice

Removed bold font in header first row since it is differently colored anyway

Works fine now

The compilable MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lclc}

    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .839,  .89,  .737} {Faixa de habitantes} & {Coeficiente} & {Faixa de habitantes} & {Coeficiente} \\

    {Até 10.188} & {0.6}& {De 61.129 a 71.316}& {2.4} \\

    {De 10.189 a 13.584} & {0.8} & {De 71.317 a 81.504} & {2.6} \\

    {De 13.585 a 16.980} & {1.0} & {De 81.505 a 91.692} & {2.8} \\

    {De 16.981 a 23.772} & {1.2} & {De 91.693 a 101.880} & {3.0} \\

    {De 23.773 a 30.564} & {1.4} & {De 101.881 a 115.464} & {3.2} \\

    {De 30.565 a 37.356} & {1.6} & {De 115.465 a 129.048} & {3.4} \\

    {De 37.357 a 44.148} & {1.8} & {De 129.049 a 142.632} & {3.6} \\

    {De 44.149 a 50.940} & {2.0} & {De 142.633 a 156.216} & {3.8} \\

    {De 50.941 a 61.128} & {2.2} & {Acima de 156.216} & {4.0} \\

    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Fonte: Decreto Lei nº 1.881/1981.} \\
    \end{tabular}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```